# Willy Nilly HTTP status codes choke Apache with PHP

Tags: php, apache, http-response-codes

So I am building a rest service and it was suggested that we return "custom status codes" such as 299 or whatever we darn well please. I'm aware that no such codes are actually valid but since it's used internally it shouldn't matter.

All was well until Apache choked. I run any of following Apache returns a 500 error:

```
http_response_code(299);
// OR
header("HTTP/1.1 299 Crazy Request Dude", true, 299);
// OR
header(" ", false, 299);
```

Does Apache not like my status code? Can I make it submit?

The hard part is Apache doesn't put anything in it's error logs pertaining to the error. If I remove the custom status code, everything is fine again.

Comment: What Apache version are you using?

Comment: That a good question :) "Apache version 2.2.3"

Comment: I have apache 2.4.6 and everything works fine. I can send custom response code. Sadly I can't easily downgrade to 2.2 but there is really small amount of similar problems in google so I think it works for others. What I could find is a bug with mod_proxy that could output `500` status code when using custom status code https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=900827. Are you using mod_proxy?

Comment: Good find. mod_proxy is enabled, but not used for anything. In the bug given they were using the proxy server as a load balancer.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off? Are you using mod_php, fastcgi or other?

Comment: I searched and found all references to "proxy" and commented them out. I still get the same 500 error. Good thoughts

Comment: So, is it mod_php, fastcgi or other?

Comment: I believe mod_php. It's not cgi, but I don't see "mod_php" explicitly listed. I find: LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so in the config file and phpinfo tells me "Server API Apache 2.0 Handler" which others have said can be a sign of mod_php

Comment: Weird. You sure there are is no proxy or something similar between user and server machine? Something like `user <-> reverse proxy <-> server`? You can try login to server using ssh console, creating `index.php` file in `localhost` document root with `header("HTTP/1.1 299 Crazy Request Dude", true, 299);` inside and checking if `curl -i localhost` returns proper headers. Tell me if this works.